# Column name of last non zero value in row in Excel

Tags: excel

How I can get column name of last non zero value in row, using Excel functions.

Example:

A:E - columns with values
x - function result

```
A B C D E x

0 0 1 0 0 C
1 0 2 1 2 E
0 1 1 0 1 E
1 1 1 1 1 E
0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Why?  will you use that in another formula to return something else?

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes. In real example each column is related to time (1st period, 2nd period...) I would like to calculate a difference between start date and date of last occurrence (end date).

Comment: You need to show the full problem, It is easier to do what you want in one step instead of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=IFERROR(MID(ADDRESS(ROW(),MAX(IF(A2:E2,COLUMN(A2:E2)))),2,SEARCH("$",ADDRESS(ROW(),MAX(IF(A2:E2,COLUMN(A2:E2)))),2)-2),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
=IFERROR(CHAR(AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(A1:E1)/(A1:E1<>0),1)+64),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Neat way to convert the column number into a column letter.

Comment: @ScottCraner I didn't mention that I need it for whole column range.

Comment: @Kulis not sure what you mean,  You just copy the formula down, the column.

Answer (score 1):

These are array-formulas that must be entered using `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`:

This works up to ZZ:

`=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(MID(CELL("address",OFFSET(A1,0,MAX(IF(A1:AA1<>0,COLUMN(A1:AA1),0))-1)),2,2),"$",""),"")`

This works for all columns:

`=IFERROR(MID(CELL("address",OFFSET(A1,0,MAX(IF(A1:AAA1<>0,COLUMN(A1:AAA1),0))-1)),2,FIND("$",MID(CELL("address",OFFSET(A1,0,MAX(IF(A1:AAA1<>0,COLUMN(A1:AAA1),0))-1)),2,99))-1),"")`

Update: The accepted answer is more efficient. It assumes numeric values but could be easily updated to handle non-numeric values as well. However it could be optimised further:

`=IFERROR(MID(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MAX(IF(A2:XED2,COLUMN(A2:XED2)))),"$1",""),2,3),"")`